# Remove letters from git commit id using qmake

Tags: git, qt, qmake

I want to, someway, include git commit id as part fo the Qt qmake `VERSION` number,
which is composed by four sub-numbers (i.e. 12345.12345.12345.12345).

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#version

Each number must be in the range from 0 to 65535.

Since git commit id is composed by letters and numbers I need to remove the numbers, considering

```
0727d89429bfccd695fae691cf254fdef06ed1be
```

I want to end up with

```
07278
```

The first numbers that will fit in 0 to 65535, from left to right.

So, in one step I have to cut part of the commit. That I can do with `str_member()`

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#str-member

But how to replace/remove the letters?

Comment: This isn't really a Git issue, but the number that Git prints is actually just a single number, between 0 and 2^160-1, represented in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). But it *looks* random and no matter how you convert it, will end up looking random; *version* numbers shouldn't look or be random at all, but rather should increase over time. Rather than using the commit hash ID, consider using Git tags and doing some sort of semantic versioning with those.

Comment: To me it seems like a XY problem as well. As @torek says, consider using git tags. I can give you the script I am using if you like.